# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' Linux with AWS-SDK

Tags: c++, linux, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-cpp

I am using aws sdk for linux to transfer file to s3. I have compiled the shared library of aws sdk.
Transfer of file fails with bad alloc error so thought to explore the example given by aws-sdk.
I am trying to run the example to list the bucket on s3 [link](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/cpp/example_code/s3/list_buckets.cpp).
Compiling the application using command:

```
g++ testingAws.cpp  -I . -L  . -laws-cpp-sdk-transfer -laws-cpp-sdk-core -laws-cpp-sdk-s3
```

Everytime the executables terminates with message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Bad alloc happens when it invokes the function:
`AwsDoc::S3::PutObject(bucket_name, object_name, clientConfig);`
Any suggestion if I am missing something. As well how to debug bad alloc issue.

I tried to list the bucket on my s3 server.
Backtrace:

```
Backtrace: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what():
  std::bad_alloc Thread 1 "a.out" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140737314626112) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44 44
  ./nptl/pthread_kill.c: No such file or directory.
  (gdb) bt 
  #0  __pthread_kill_implementation (no_tid=0, signo=6, threadid=140737314626112) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:44
  #1  __pthread_kill_internal (signo=6, threadid=140737314626112) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:78
  #2  __GI___pthread_kill (threadid=140737314626112, signo=signo@entry=6) at ./nptl/pthread_kill.c:89
  #3  0x00007ffff6b2d476 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/posix/raise.c:26
  #4  0x00007ffff6b137f3 in __GI_abort () at ./stdlib/abort.c:79
  #5  0x00007ffff6dd5bbe in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  #6  0x00007ffff6de124c in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  #7  0x00007ffff6de12b7 in std::terminate() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  #8  0x00007ffff6de1518 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  #9  0x00007ffff6dd57cc in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  #10 0x00007ffff6e7ee6f in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  #11 0x00007ffff6e7f22d in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
  #12 0x000055555555b58d in Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest::SetBucket(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
  #13 0x000055555555a78b in AwsDoc::S3::PutObject(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration const&) ()
  #14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? () 
  (gdb
```

Comment: Have you compiled the sdk with the same compiler as your applications? Which compiler? Which version? Are your applications using the [c++11 abi](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)?

Comment: Yes I have compiled the SDK and application on same machine. It's virtual box ubuntu machine. 

gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

It's been resolved. I was using header files that were from windows. There was no compilation error so thought everything should work as expectation but later I have taken header files from the Linux machine and that has resolved it.